# How to load a module in Gentoo?

Tags: gentoo, kernel-modules

I am using Gentoo, with kernel 2.6.30, and I tried to load a module with `modprobe usbcore`, but it fails with  `modprobe: module 'usbcore' not found`.

However, I can find a directory with that name in the directory `/sys/module/`. What is wrong here?

Comment: By gentoo 2.6.30 I assume that's the kernel version. Right?

Comment: Module binaries are located in `/lib/modules/<kernel-version>/` and not in `/sys/module/`. The way you load a module is in no way different then in other distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether the module you are trying to insert is present or not using

```
$ modprobe -l | grep usbcore
```

Generally all the modules are present in the path `/lib/modules/<kernel-version>/kernel/`

If present, you can then insert the module using `modprobe` or `insmod` command.

```
$ insmod <complete/path/to/module>
```

**EDIT:** If `modprobe -l` option is not there, you can run the following find command to list all the modules:

```
root@localhost#  find /lib/modules/`uname -r` -name '*.ko'
```

Comment: `modprobe` has no option `-l`

Comment: @Alex: I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, it seems the module is NOT available.

Answer (score 1):

if you already have the directory /sys/module/usbcore i would assume the module is already loaded. check if 'lsmod' or 'cat /proc/modules' are listing it, to be sure if its loaded or not.

one possible reason why modprobe might tell you it can't find the module, could be that its not indexed in /lib/modules/kernel version/modules.dep. you can regenerate this file by submitting 'depmod'.

since modprobe doesn't know howto load this module. I would guess that you probably already have it loaded because its in your initrd.

Comment: Nice, `depmod` saved my day!